# Need help in getting my head around Angular Material 2 Date picker formatting

Tags: javascript, angular, date, datepicker, angular-material2

I am new to Web development and Angular 2 in specific. I am working on this app that needs date selection on various screens in the input fields that are part of one or the other reactive form. 
I tagged along the newly introduced datepicker from Angular Material 2 framework but i have failed in configuring the correct date format on for the same. 
Here is what i am wanting to do..
A user when enters the date in the field using the datepicker, system shows the date as 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. However, i want this format to be 'dd/mm/yyyy'. Also, then i wanted to be able to change the date format to 'yyyy-mm-dd' while sending data to backend server for storage.

During retrieval of data, i must re-parse the format from 'yyyy-mm-dd' back to 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

I read a little about date adapters but didn't quite understood what it was all about.

Any help from the friends here is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Navin

Answer (score 1):

Md-datepicker has following sections in its documentation:

- Customizing the date implementation
- Customizing the parse and
  display

https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker

Or, as an alternative, use can use the following datepicker library. This project has very good documentation/example on how to change date format.

https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker

You can also google following libraries for more information on datepicker customization.

- PrimeNG
- ngx-bootstrap/datepicker
- ng-bootstrap/NgbDatepicker

Hope this helps!